# Can we use ternary operator within an if statement?

Tags: c++

My teacher says we can't use a ternary operator within an if statement as it's an alternative for it... Can anyone please tell me if we can use ternary operators within an if statement in c++?

Comment: Get a better teacher.

Comment: please include an example in the question

Comment: There is nothing special with the expressions used for conditions inside an `if`. It can by *any* expression, including expressions using the ternary operator.

Comment: Next they'll be saying you can't use the assignment operator in an if statement

Comment: maybe the teacher meant pitfalls like if (x == a ? 1 : 0), dynamic right value for x depending on condition a, this fails, if ternary moved to variable and then checked against x it works or if added additional brackets around it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

A ternary conditional operator is an *expression* with type inferred from the type of the final two arguments. And *expressions* can be used as the conditional in an `if` statement.

An example is the perversion

```
if (unemployed ? false : true)
```

which stands in for

```
if (!unemployed)
```

Naturally, whether or not it's a *good* thing to do depends on the context.

Comment: Thank u! Finally have a proof to get back the freaking 3 marks I deserved but tha guy took from my life!

Without your answer, I would have become ghost rider for revenge!

Comment: @AashrayKrishnani: But approach it delicately. I'm often called out by junior members of my team, but expect them to do so politely.

Comment: Oooh, a question for [academia.se].

Answer (score 7):

The basic answer is: Yes, you can.
As @Bathsheba already pointed out: It may not always make sense.

A more sensible example might be something like this:

```
if (use_locking ? readLocked() : readUnlocked())
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I know this question is old. However I came accross another useful example I used recently in my code:

```c
if ( by_start ? (tmp_segment1->start > tmp_segment2->start) : 
                (tmp_segment1->end > tmp_segment2->end) )
{
   ...
}
```

It's basically about sorting a list by the element's member variable start or end. By using the ternary operator inside the if the code becomes significantly smaller but it is still readable.